# Count surviving individuals across time in r

Tags: r, dplyr, survival-analysis

I am trying to count the number of individuals that appear in each year of my data set, starting with the latest year. My data set looks something like this:

| id | grade | school year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | "17-18" |
| 1 | 10 | "18-19" |
| 1 | 11 | "19-20" |
| 1 | 12 | "20-21" |
| 2 | 9 | "17-18" |
| 2 | 10 | "18-19" |
| 2 | 11 | "20-21" |
| 3 | 11 | "20-21" |
| 3 | 12 | "21-22" |
| 4 | 9 | "17-18" |
| 4 | 10 | "18-19" |
| 4 | 11 | "19-20" |
| 4 | 12 | "20-21" |

I want to know the number of student IDs in the year 20-21 that also appear in the 19-20, and persist to appear in the year 18-19, and again appear again in 17-18. I would like counts for the number IDs in 20-21 surviving each of the previous years.

I need a table that looks like this:

| # of IDs in 20-21 | #of IDs from 20-21 that were present in 19-20 | #of IDs from 20-21 that were present in 18-19 | #of IDs from 20-21 that were present in 17-18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 180 | 150 | 140 |

I have no clue how to even begin calculating this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a `filter()` statement.  In the code below, the filter is looking for groups where each of the four school year designations is present for a particular `id`.  It is doing this by, for example, `"17-18 %in% school_year`, which looks for `"17-18"` among the values of `school_year` for each specific `id`.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id,  ~grade, ~school_year,
1,  9,  "17-18",
1,  10, "18-19",
1,  11, "19-20",
1,  12, "20-21",
2,  9,  "17-18",
2,  10, "18-19",
2,  11, "20-21",
3,  11, "20-21",
3,  12, "21-22",
4,  9,  "17-18",
4,  10, "18-19",
4,  11, "19-20",
4,  12, "20-21")
```

Here is the data filtered down to include only the `id`'s that meet the condition.

```r
filt_dat <- dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter("17-18" %in% school_year & "18-19" %in% school_year 
         & "19-20" %in% school_year & "20-21" %in% school_year) 
filt_dat
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id grade school_year
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
#> 1     1     9 17-18      
#> 2     1    10 18-19      
#> 3     1    11 19-20      
#> 4     1    12 20-21      
#> 5     4     9 17-18      
#> 6     4    10 18-19      
#> 7     4    11 19-20      
#> 8     4    12 20-21
```

If you just want the unique individual `id` values, you could do this:

```r
filt_dat %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(id) %>% 
  pull %>% 
  unique
#> [1] 1 4
```

---

#### Edit: Answer to updated question

If an observation has to be in 19-20 to be counted in 18-19, then you can figure out whether ids are in each year, pivot the data longer and then take the cumulative product over the in-year values.

```r
dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(in_20_21 = "20-21" %in% school_year, 
            in_19_20 = "19-20" %in% school_year, 
            in_18_19 = "18-19" %in% school_year, 
            in_17_18 = "17-18" %in% school_year) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to="yr", values_to="surv") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(surv = cumprod(surv)) %>% 
  group_by(yr) %>% 
  summarise(n=sum(surv))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   yr           n
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 in_17_18     2
#> 2 in_18_19     2
#> 3 in_19_20     2
#> 4 in_20_21     4
```

If an observation doesn't have to be in 19-20 to be counted in 18-19, then you could filter by the observations who are in 20-21, and then just count the observations in each year:

```r
dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(in_20_21 = "20-21" %in% school_year, 
            in_19_20 = "19-20" %in% school_year, 
            in_18_19 = "18-19" %in% school_year, 
            in_17_18 = "17-18" %in% school_year) %>% 
  filter(in_20_21) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to="yr", values_to="surv") %>% 
  group_by(yr) %>% 
  summarise(n=sum(surv))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   yr           n
#>   <chr>    <int>
#> 1 in_17_18     3
#> 2 in_18_19     3
#> 3 in_19_20     2
#> 4 in_20_21     4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Thank you so much. But what I'm looking for is the counts. So I would like is a table that shows the number of IDs that persist each year. I'll update the post with more info

Comment: Does an observation that appears in 20-21, then does not appear in 19-20 then appears again in 18-19 get counted in the 18-19 group, or must it be there in all years after?

Comment: Yes, the observation (obs) in 20-21 should be in 19-20 and then the 19-20 obs should be in 18-19 and then the 18-19 obs should be in 17-18.  Therefore, your first solution after editing your response was correct! Thank you so much! Very helpful!!